# PrimeFaces Extensions: Why is <pe:resetInput> rendered?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have a small problem with PrimeFaces Extensions.
I use the Tag  inside a CommandButton.
The functionality is OK, but the "pe-Tag" is rendered and makes a gap between two buttons, which is bigger than without the tag. (you can see it on the picture)

Any idea how I have to configure my button, so that the "pe-Tag" is not rendered?

Picture:

[image]

Button-Code:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{labels.abort}"
                            icon="ui-icon-cancel" 
                            process="@this" 
                            update=":workflowContentPanel" 
                            immediate="true" 
                            actionListener="#{workflowHandler.abort}"
                            rendered="#{myBean.entity}">
        <pe:resetInput target="workflowPG"/>
 </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found out.
Sometimes Eclipse does make funny things.
There was an "invisible" blank inside my code. Don't know why, haven't used auto format or something similar ;-(

The blank was between the closing bracket from  and the opening bracket from